# Neo4j connection error as more concurrent users connect

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

- Neo4j 3.5.12 Community
- Python 3.6.9
- neo4j-driver==1.7.6
- neobolt==1.7.17
- Ubuntu Server 18.04
- Flask 1.1.2

A web server I run has suddenly experienced a 2000% increase in traffic.  Everything was working fine before this increase.  However, now I'm seeing the following error after a few hours (unsure how long, but within 5 hours) of heavy traffic and then fail constantly after that.  Like connections are not being closed or something.

```
     db = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:MYPORTNO", auth=basic_auth(DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, encrypted=False)
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 120, in driver
     return Driver(uri, **config)
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 161, in __new__
     return subclass(uri, **config)
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 235, in __new__
     pool.release(pool.acquire())
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 715, in acquire
     return self.acquire_direct(self.address)
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 608, in acquire_direct
     connection = self.connector(address, error_handler=self.connection_error_handler)
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 232, in connector
     return connect(address, **dict(config, **kwargs))
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 972, in connect
     raise last_error
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 962, in connect
     s = _connect(resolved_address, **config)
   File "/home/ubuntu/api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 843, in _connect
     raise ServiceUnavailable("Failed to establish connection to {!r} (reason {})".format(resolved_address, error))
neobolt.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection to ('127.0.0.1', MYPORTNO) (reason [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

If I restart apache it works again, so currently as a bandaid, I'm doing that on a cron job every few hours, but that only seems to partially work.

I increased the page cache and heap calculating according to [this article](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/).

I increased the Open Files Limit from the default 1024 to 50000.

I doubled the server spec.

Structurally I create a database driver instance in a config file:

Config file:

```
db = None
def getDB():
    global db
    if not db:
        db = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:XXXXXX", auth=basic_auth(DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD), encrypted=False) 

    return db
```

I can then make queries in my module files as follows. I believe the following syntax properly manages connections being opened and closed due to the `with` statement, and so shouldn't leave open connections:

Module file:

```
db = config.getDB()

with db.session() as s:
        with s.begin_transaction() as tx:
            tx.run("the cypher", {the params})
```

I am also seeing the following error in the logs, although I'm not sure they are directly related.

```
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to fix it please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had a cron job that was running every 10 minutes and was leaving the driver instance open each time.  Schoolboy error.